# Recurrence relation $a_n = 4a_{n-1} - 3a_{n-2} + 2^n + n + 3$ with $a_{0} = 1$ and $a_{1} = 4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

This is a nonhomogeneous recurrence relation, so there is a homogeneous and a particular solution.

Homogenous:

$a_n - 4a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-2} = 0$

$r^2 - 4r + 3 = 0$

$(r - 3)(r - 1)$

$a_n^h = \alpha(3^n) + \beta(1^n)$

This is where my solution stops because I don't know how to solve the particular solution since it would be $a_n - 4a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-2} = 2^n + n + 3$ and I'm not sure what form it should be. Would it be $A_0(r^n) + A_1(n) + A_2$ where $A_n$ is a constant or not?

I've tried solving it with that form and it ended like this:

$A_0(2^n) + A_1(n) + A_2 - 4(A_0(2^{n-1}) + A_1(n-1) + A_2) + 3(A_0(2^{n-2}) + A_1(n-2) + A_2) = 2^n + n + 3$

After simplifying and dividing $2^{n-2}$:

$A_0(2^n) - 4A_0(2^{n-1}) + 3A_0(2^{n-2}) - 4 = n + 3 + 2A_1(n) + 2A_2 - 2A_1$

And that's where I stop since I don't know what to do next.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Use a_{n-1} to get $a_{n-1}$

Comment: @jjagmath can you explain further?

Comment: @Clover, I edited as jjagmath suggested. Please check I didn't change anything by mistake.

Comment: Please, you can read the [MSE-${\tt MathJax}$ Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Thanks.

Comment: What are the initial values for this recurrence?

Comment: If you want a block of more than one characters to be formated you must put the inside brackets.   \$a_7\$ will render $a_7$ with the $7$ subscripted but \$a_71\$ will render $a_71$ with the $7$ subscripted and the $1$ not.  But if you write \$a_{71}\$ then everything in brackets will be subscripted as $a_{71}$.  \$a_(n-1)\$ rendered as $a_(n-1)$ is absolutely unreadible.  Use \$a_{(n-1)}\$ ($a_{(n-1)}$) or better yet \$a_{n-1}\$ ($a_{n-1}$).

Comment: Say $y_1$ is a particular solution of $a_n - 4a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-2} = 2^n, y_2$ is a particular solution of $a_n - 4a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-2} =n$ and $y_3$ of $a_n - 4a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-2} =3$. Is $y_1+y_2+y_3$ a particular solution of your original recurrence?

Comment: @cosmo5 you accidentally removed the initial values but I added it back again

Comment: @JoshuaWang $a_{0} = 1$ and $a_{1} = 4$

Answer (score 1):

So we have
$$
a_{\,n}  - 4a_{\,n - 1}  + 3a_{\,n - 2}  = 2^{\,n}  + n + 3 = q(n)
$$
and the solutions to the homogeneous equations are
$$
3^{\,n} ,\;1
$$

The homogeneous equation has constant coefficients and
$$
q(n) = 2^{\,n}  + \left( {n + 3} \right)
$$
is the sum of two terms of the form
$$
c^{\,n}  \cdot {\rm polynomial}(n)
$$

Then the theory says that in this case we can look for particular solutions of the form
$$
2^{\,n} \left( {An + B} \right),\quad C\left( {n + 3} \right)^{\,2}  + D\left( {n + 3} \right) + E
$$
(*method of Undetermined Coefficients*).

Since the constant term $E$ is already a homogeneous solution we can omit it and with simple passages we get
$$
A = 0,\;B =  - 4,\;C =  - 1/4,\;D =  - 1
$$

So the solution is
$$
a_{\,n}  = \alpha \,3^{\,n}  + \beta  - 4 \cdot 2^{\,n}  - {{\left( {n + 3} \right)^{\,2} } \over 4} - \left( {n + 3} \right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in including a constant term in the particular solution because constants are part of the solution of the homogeneous equation. Try $A_0 2^n + A_1 n^2+ A_2 n$.

This way you will conclude that the general solution is given by
$$
a_n = \alpha 3^n + \beta - 2^{n+2} -\frac 14 n^2 -\frac 52 n.
$$

Now you just need to compute $\alpha, \beta$  so that the initial conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Should the characteristic root then be $r^2 - 4r + 3 = 3$? And why $A_{1}n^2 + A_{2}n$ instead of $A_{1}n + A_{2}$ for the particular solution?

Comment: @Clover The characteristic polynomial is always relative to the homogeneous equation. The inicial choice for the particular solution would indeed be $A_0 2^n + A_1 n + A_0$ but, as you have seen, when you plug it into the equation you get an impossible system for computing the constants. When this happens, a common fix is to multiply by $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach. Let $A(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n z^n$ be the ordinary generating function for $a_n$.  Then the recurrence relation implies that
\begin{align}
A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z 
&= \sum_{n\ge 2}\left(4a_{n-1} - 3a_{n-2} + 2^n + n + 3\right)z^n \\
&= 4z \sum_{n\ge 2} a_{n-1} z^{n-1} - 3z^2 \sum_{n\ge 2} a_{n-2} z^{n-2} + \sum_{n\ge 2} (2z)^n + z \sum_{n\ge 2} n z^{n-1} + 3\sum_{n\ge 2}z^n \\
&= 4z (A(z)-a_0)- 3z^2 A(z) + \frac{(2z)^2}{1-2z} + z\left(\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}-1\right) + \frac{3z^2}{1-z},
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
A(z) 
&= \frac{a_0 + a_1 z -4 a_0 z + \frac{4z^2}{1-2z} + \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}-z + \frac{3z^2}{1-z}}{1-4z+3z^2}\\
&= \frac{1 - z + \frac{4z^2}{1-2z} + \frac{z}{(1-z)^2} + \frac{3z^2}{1-z}}{1-4z+3z^2}\\
&= \frac{1 - 4 z + 14 z^2 - 24 z^3 + 12 z^4}{(1 - 2 z) (1 - 3 z)(1 - z)^3 } \\
&= -\frac{4}{1-2 z} + \frac{39/8}{1-3 z} + \frac{19/8}{1-z} - \frac{7/4}{(1-z)^2} - \frac{1/2}{(1-z)^3} \\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0}\left(-4\cdot 2^n + \frac{39}{8}\cdot3^n + \frac{19}{8} - \frac{7}{4}\binom{n+1}{1} - \frac{1}{2}\binom{n+2}{2}\right)z^n,
\end{align}
which immediately implies that
\begin{align}
a_n &= -4\cdot 2^n + \frac{39}{8}\cdot3^n + \frac{19}{8} - \frac{7}{4}\binom{n+1}{1} - \frac{1}{2}\binom{n+2}{2} \\
&= \frac{- 2^{n + 5} + 13\cdot 3^{n + 1} -2 n^2 - 20 n + 1}{8}.
\end{align}